# What's a good way to assign the result of an evaluation to a variable in one line?

Tags: javascript

I know the following is a way to do it

```js
let demo = (() => {
    let data = getData();
    alterData();
    return data;
})();
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result, i.e. other than the `(function())()` expression?

**Edit: sorry, bad question. Didn't know it's called IIFE. Felt it was somewhat of a hack, so I asked the question, but it's actually not.**

Comment: Why don't you just write `let demo = getData(); alterData();`? Yes, using an IIFE is a totally fine approach when it is useful, but it's really unclear what problem you are trying to solve and why you care about the number of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) for more information on this

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better to to achieve the same result?

Indeed, there is:

```js
let demo = 1 + 1;
```

Comment: lmaoo i m pretty sure he meant by using functions xD

Answer (score 0):

Just take the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) without curly brackets.

```js
let demo = (() => 1 + 1)();

console.log(demo);
```

Answer (score 0):

`let demo = ()=>1+1;`

then call demo. Basically es6 makes these feature neat like here are some examples:

1) When no further code other then return :
`let demo = ()=>1+1;`

2) single param :
`let demo = a=>1+a;`

3) Multi params:
`let demo = (a,b)=>a+b;`

4) Some logic in the body:
`let demo = (a,b)=>{if(a>b){return b}};`